# How to set paths where to load administration theme?

Tags: theming, 8

E.g. administration themes are used only on paths that start with `/admin/`, what if I want to use administration theme on paths like `/user/`, `/users/*` or `user/login`?

There is a module for that where you can set paths where to load your admin theme https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_theme, but my question is for Drupal 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a route subscriber, where you search for routes, which have a path you want to load with the admin theme, and add the option:

```
$route->setOption('_admin_route', TRUE);
```

More info [Altering existing routes and adding new routes based on dynamic ones](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones).

**Example**

There is an example in core. You can configure the admin theme for the node edit form in UI and this route subscriber is applying this configuration:

```
namespace Drupal\node\EventSubscriber;

use Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

/**
 * Sets the _admin_route for specific node-related routes.
 */
class NodeAdminRouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * The config factory.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface
   */
  protected $configFactory;

  /**
   * Constructs a new NodeAdminRouteSubscriber.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface $config_factory
   *   The config factory.
   */
  public function __construct(ConfigFactoryInterface $config_factory) {
    $this->configFactory = $config_factory;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    if ($this->configFactory->get('node.settings')->get('use_admin_theme')) {
      foreach ($collection->all() as $route) {
        if ($route->hasOption('_node_operation_route')) {
          $route->setOption('_admin_route', TRUE);
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: I wish I knew how to code.